# Study the convergence of this: $\sum_n \frac{n! }{ 6\cdot7\cdots(n+5)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, factorial

convergence for this one:  $$\sum_n \frac{n! }{ 6\cdot7\cdots(n+5)}$$

I tried to calculate it standard and didn't got an answer...

Tried D'Alembert but didn't work.

Thank you very much for all the replies!!! I appreciate! It was very obvious...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Try following this guidelines to increase your chances of getting help in this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i!}{6\cdot 7 \cdot \cdots \cdot (i+5)} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{5!}{(i+1)(i+2)(i+3)(i+4)(i+5)} \\
\le  \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{5!}{(i+1)(i+2)} \le \sum_{i=1}^n \Big[\frac{5!}{(i+1)} -\frac{5!}{(i+2)}\Big] = \frac{5!}{2} - \frac{5!}{n+2} \to \frac{5!}{2}
$$
Since the sum is upperbounded, it's convergent.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your serie is equal to $$\sum_0^\infty {(1*2*3*4*5) \over (n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)}<120\sum_0^\infty { 1 \over (n+1)^5}$$ which trivially converges.

Comment: Why the downvote exactly?

Comment: Thank you very much! It was very obvious... The downvote wasn't from me.